# class not found autoloading psr-4

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I am learning the Composer autoloading. I have some issues with PSR-4.

I am following this tutorial: https://vegibit.com/composer-autoloading-tutorial/

I have reviewed the code a few hours but I keep having the same issue when I load the script in the browser:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'VegibitLibraryGreeting' not found
>   in C:\PHPWebPages\aldemo\aldemo4\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\PHPWebPages\aldemo\aldemo4\index.php on line 5

I have tried several solutions proposed in similar questions but I haven't solved it yet.

I attach some screenshots:

[image: Tutorial directory]
[image]
[image: composer.json and greeting.php]

Please could someone help me finding out why is happening this error.
Thank in advance.

Notes:

I am going to show the new code after the solution to allow anyone that will have the same issue can review the solution:

[image: composer.json]
[image: theme.php]
[image: index.php]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**greeting.php:**

You can't declare two namespaces in the same file. Namespace declaration should be in the very beginning of PHP file.
You also should declare namespaces as they are presented in `composer.json`:

```
namespace Vegibit\Library;
```

Split this code to separate files.

**index.php:**

```
$vb = new Vegibit\Library\Greeting();
```

Comment: You can have multiple namespaces in single file: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php